# What is the cost for becoming a reseller partner of Ubuntu?

Tags: canonical

I'm interested about [Ubuntu Reseller partnership](http://www.ubuntu.com/partners/partner-programmes), but I'm not getting full info for this; like

- How I need to pay them (will it be case to case, annually or monthly)?
- When I'll sale their Ubuntu Advantage Support, then how I'll be benefited?

When I'm clicking on the "contact" button of canonical website it takes me to "becoming a partner" page, but fact is that before apply for a partnership I need to know about this fully.

Comment: Right now it returns an 404. Are you still interested?

Comment: @Braiam I think [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/partners/partner-programmes) is what they are needing?

Answer (score 1):

You are best contacting Canonical and asking these questions direct, using the following form:

http://www.ubuntu.com/partners/contact-us